# Unable to use Client Application Services with custom MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, winforms, custom-membershipprovider

I have a Windows-Forms Application that I configured to use with an ASP.NET Service that is an Authentication service using a custom MembershipProvider.

When I call Membership.CreateUser in the Windows Application a NotSupportedException is thrown telling: "Specified method is not supported.".

I tried creating a web page in the website and test the MembershipProvider, everything works just fine when woeking from within the website.

Any ideas or link for how to use custom (not SqlMembershipProvider) MembershipProvider will be really appreciated!

**Edit**: The method ValidateUser does work.
The overriden CreateUser doesn't work
I tried
Override Sub CreateUser(.......) As MembershipUser
    Return New User()
End Sub
But I still get the same excetption as before.

Comment: @Shimmy, heads-up, if you havent' an implementation yet you might get some mileage from my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client Application Services doesn't support CreateUser method.

Here is CreateUser method source code from ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider :

```
public override MembershipUser CreateUser
(
    string username, 
    string password, 
    string email,
    string passwordQuestion,
    string passwordAnswer,
    bool isApproved,
    object providerUserKey,
    out MembershipCreateStatus status
)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that custom membership provider is when implementing an ASP.NET AJAX service (client application service). for simple windows application [My.User.CurrentPrinciple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.user.currentprincipal.aspx) can be used to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to build a json proxy over your custom provider. Something to keep well in mind is securing the proxy endpoint! SECURE THE PROXY ENDPOINT!

I have not tested every method in this class but previous implementations performed just fine so it will probably get you to where you need to go, eventurally.

SECURE THE ENDPOINT!

```
// <copyright project="Salient.ScriptModel" file="MembershipService.svc" company="Sky Sanders">
// This source is a Public Domain Dedication.
// http://skysanders.net/subtext
// Attribution is appreciated
// </copyright>
// <version>1.0</version>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Salient.ScriptModel
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "Salient.ScriptModel", Name = "MembershipProvider")]
    public interface IMembershipProvider
    {
        string ProviderName { get; set; }

        [OperationContract]
        DateTime TestInput(DateTime date);

        [OperationContract]
        ProviderProperties GetProviderProperties();

        [OperationContract]
        MembershipUser GetUserByKey(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline);

        [OperationContract]
        MembershipCreateResult CreateUser(string username, string password,
                                          string email, string passwordQuestion,
                                          string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved,
                                          object providerUserKey);

        [OperationContract]
        MembershipCreateResult AddUser(MembershipUser user);

        [OperationContract]
        bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password,
                                             string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer);

        [OperationContract]
        string GetPassword(string username, string answer);

        [OperationContract]
        bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword);

        [OperationContract]
        string ResetPassword(string username, string answer);

        [OperationContract]
        void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user);

        [OperationContract]
        bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);

        [OperationContract]
        bool UnlockUser(string userName);

        [OperationContract]
        MembershipUser GetUserByName(string username, bool userIsOnline);

        [OperationContract]
        string GetUserNameByEmail(string email);

        [OperationContract]
        bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData);

        [OperationContract]
        MembershipFindResult GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize);

        [OperationContract]
        int GetNumberOfUsersOnline();

        [OperationContract]
        MembershipFindResult FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex,
                                             int pageSize);

        [OperationContract]
        MembershipFindResult FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex,
                                              int pageSize);
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class MembershipProvider : IMembershipProvider
    {
        private System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider Provider
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProviderName))
                {
                    return Membership.Provider;
                }
                return Membership.Providers[ProviderName];
            }
        }

        #region IMembershipProvider Members

        public DateTime TestInput(DateTime date)
        {
            return date;
        }

        public string ProviderName { get; set; }

        public ProviderProperties GetProviderProperties()
        {
            var returnValue = new ProviderProperties
                                  {
                                      ApplicationName = Provider.ApplicationName,
                                      EnablePasswordReset = Provider.EnablePasswordReset,
                                      EnablePasswordRetrieval = Provider.EnablePasswordRetrieval,
                                      MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts = Provider.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts,
                                      MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters =
                                          Provider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters,
                                      MinRequiredPasswordLength = Provider.MinRequiredPasswordLength,
                                      PasswordAttemptWindow = Provider.PasswordAttemptWindow,
                                      PasswordFormat = Provider.PasswordFormat,
                                      PasswordStrengthRegularExpression = Provider.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression,
                                      RequiresQuestionAndAnswer = Provider.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer,
                                      RequiresUniqueEmail = Provider.RequiresUniqueEmail
                                  };
            return returnValue;
        }

        public MembershipUser GetUserByKey(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            return Provider.GetUser(providerUserKey, userIsOnline);
        }

        public MembershipCreateResult CreateUser(string username, string password,
                                                 string email, string passwordQuestion,
                                                 string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved,
                                                 object providerUserKey)
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus status;
            MembershipUser user = Provider.CreateUser(username, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer,
                                                      isApproved,
                                                      providerUserKey, out status);
            return new MembershipCreateResult(user, status);
        }

        public MembershipCreateResult AddUser(MembershipUser user)
        {
            return new MembershipCreateResult(user, MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail);
        }

        public bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password,
                                                    string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
        {
            return Provider.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(username, password, newPasswordQuestion, newPasswordAnswer);
        }

        public string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            return Provider.GetPassword(username, answer);
        }

        public bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            return Provider.ChangePassword(username, oldPassword, newPassword);
        }

        public string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            return Provider.ResetPassword(username, answer);
        }

        public void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
        {
            Provider.UpdateUser(user);
        }

        public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return Provider.ValidateUser(username, password);
        }

        public bool UnlockUser(string userName)
        {
            return Provider.UnlockUser(userName);
        }

        public MembershipUser GetUserByName(string username, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            return Provider.GetUser(username, userIsOnline);
        }

        public string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
        {
            return Provider.GetUserNameByEmail(email);
        }

        public bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
        {
            return Provider.DeleteUser(username, deleteAllRelatedData);
        }

        public MembershipFindResult GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            int totalRecords;
            MembershipUserCollection users = Provider.GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);
            var list = new List<MembershipUser>();
            foreach (MembershipUser user in users)
            {
                list.Add(user);
            }
            return new MembershipFindResult(list, totalRecords);
        }

        public int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
        {
            return Provider.GetNumberOfUsersOnline();
        }

        public MembershipFindResult FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex,
                                                    int pageSize)
        {
            int totalRecords;
            MembershipUserCollection users = Provider.FindUsersByName(usernameToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize,
                                                                      out totalRecords);
            var list = new List<MembershipUser>();
            foreach (MembershipUser user in users)
            {
                list.Add(user);
            }
            return new MembershipFindResult(list, totalRecords);
        }

        public MembershipFindResult FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex,
                                                     int pageSize)
        {
            int totalRecords;
            MembershipUserCollection users = Provider.FindUsersByEmail(emailToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize,
                                                                       out totalRecords);
            var list = new List<MembershipUser>();
            foreach (MembershipUser user in users)
            {
                list.Add(user);
            }
            return new MembershipFindResult(list, totalRecords);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MembershipFindResult
    {
        [DataMember] public int RecordCount;
        [DataMember] public IEnumerable<MembershipUser> Users;

        public MembershipFindResult()
        {
        }

        public MembershipFindResult(IEnumerable<MembershipUser> users, int recordCount)
        {
            Users = users;
            RecordCount = recordCount;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MembershipCreateResult
    {
        [DataMember] public MembershipCreateStatus CreateStatus;
        [DataMember] public MembershipUser User;

        public MembershipCreateResult()
        {
        }

        public MembershipCreateResult(MembershipUser user, MembershipCreateStatus createStatus)
        {
            User = user;
            CreateStatus = createStatus;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ProviderProperties
    {
        public ProviderProperties()
        {
        }

        public ProviderProperties(bool enablePasswordRetrieval, bool enablePasswordReset, bool requiresQuestionAndAnswer,
                                  int maxInvalidPasswordAttempts,
                                  int passwordAttemptWindow, bool requiresUniqueEmail,
                                  MembershipPasswordFormat passwordFormat, int minRequiredPasswordLength,
                                  int minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters,
                                  string passwordStrengthRegularExpression, string applicationName)
        {
            EnablePasswordRetrieval = enablePasswordRetrieval;
            EnablePasswordReset = enablePasswordReset;
            RequiresQuestionAndAnswer = requiresQuestionAndAnswer;
            MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts = maxInvalidPasswordAttempts;
            PasswordAttemptWindow = passwordAttemptWindow;
            RequiresUniqueEmail = requiresUniqueEmail;
            PasswordFormat = passwordFormat;
            MinRequiredPasswordLength = minRequiredPasswordLength;
            MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters = minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters;
            PasswordStrengthRegularExpression = passwordStrengthRegularExpression;
            ApplicationName = applicationName;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public bool EnablePasswordRetrieval { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool EnablePasswordReset { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int PasswordAttemptWindow { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool RequiresUniqueEmail { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int MinRequiredPasswordLength { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

EDIT: had to remove comments to fit. keep an eye on my blog for a full implementation

p.s. SECURE THIS ENDPOINT!

Answer (score -1):

[This page](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050216.htm) shows how to implement a custom membership provider. I'm not sure it will help with your problem, though.